# Raise a specific error message if the number of arguments passed in a function call is not the same as the number of arguments in its definition?

Tags: python, exception

Suppose I have a function with only a single definition in Python

```
def foo(x, y, z):
    return x + y + z
```

and then later I call this function like this:

```
foo(20, 30)
```

Of course, Python by default throws an error regarding the number of arguments. But is there a way to customize this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set default values of the parameters to None or some other value that would be an invalid input:

```
def foo(x=None, y=None, z=None):
    for param_value in (x, y, z):
        if param_value is None:
            raise ValueError("Need to provide foo, bar and baz values")
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be another, better approach, but one solution is to let your function take any amount of arguments and then check the amount of arguments passed through when the function is called:

```
def foo(*args):
    if len(args) != 3:
        raise TypeError("Custom error!")
    return sum(args)

foo(1, 2, 3)
# 6
foo(1, 2)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "<stdin>", line 3, in foo
# TypeError: Custom error!
```

Comment: That's a good way too, although, for my purpose, I wanted specific variable names for the arguments. The function was a contrived example.